# std::getline deal with \n, \r and \r\n

Tags: c++, getline, istringstream

I'm reading data in from a text file and do so line by line using `std::getline`. This by default reads up to a newline character `\n`. My code relies on this.

However, it turns out I have to deal with data that may be generated in different environments ie where the newline character is `\r` (Mac), `\n` (Unix) or `\r\n` (Windows)

Is there a simple fix so that I can do something like

```
std::getline(data,str,'\r\n','\r','\n');
```

but get it to first look for `\r\n` and then `\r` and `\n` so that it will return a 'line' independently of whatever environment generated it?

**Or more generally: Is there a way of using `std::getline` to return a 'line' for any type of commonly used line break/carriage return?**

At the moment all I have come up with is

```
std::vector<int> size(3);
for (int i=0;i<3;i++){

    data.open(c_string_file_name);
    switch (i){
        case 0: std::getline(data,str,'\r\n');size[0]=str.size();break;
        case 1: std::getline(data,str,'\r');size[1]=str.size();break;
        case 2: std::getline(data,str,'\n');size[2]=str.size();break;
    }
    data.close();

}

int min=std::min_element(size.begin(),size.end());

std::string delim;

switch (min){
    case 0:delim='\r\n';break;
    case 1:delim='\r';break;
    case 2:delim='\n';break;
}
if ((size[0]==size[1])&&(min==1)){
    delim='\r\n';
}
//rest of code use

std::getline(data,str,delim.c_str());
```

Based on the assumption that, assuming there are line breaks, the relevant delimiter will produce the shortest 'line'. Also accounting for the fact that `\r` and `\r\n` will have the same length string if it is an `\r\n` delimiter

Comment: `std::getline` will transform `'\n'` into the system-specific newline.

Comment: I'm dealing with a horrid example where (not my fault), data from an MS excel spreadsheet is copied into a Mac text file. It only works if I use `std::getline(data,str,'\r')`. In that instance it is not doing what you say.

Comment: Can you not check for both \n and \r\n?

Comment: I'm asking how to do that. But it's not that simple. If it checks for `\r` it will find it even if the actual line break character being used is `\r\n`

Comment: according to getline definition: getline, "Extracts characters from is and stores them into str until the delimitation character delim is found (or the newline character, '\n')" So it sound like std::getline(data,str,'\r') is all you need

Comment: @Pandrei Not according to what I'm seeing. If I do that it will read in a 'line' full of linebreaks.

Comment: @Pandrei That isn't what the definition says: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/ It only searches for the newline character if the delim field isn't used